# C / C++ SHIFT / OFFSET / MOVE a Bitmap to the LEFT or RIGHT?

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, bitmapimage

I say I have a monochrome 240x60 bitmap with a bit depth of 1, in a byte array in memory, like

```
BYTE bitMapBytes[2048]
```

Assuming that the bytes are *all and only* image data bytes (no BITMAPINFOHEADER, BITMAPFILEHEADER), how do I shift the bitmap image left and right?

For example, how do I shift the left by 40 pixels, with wrap-around behavior?

In my experiments, I had some success with shifting to the right by doing

```
int offset = 40;
for(int i = 0; i < bitmapBytes; i++){
    newBitmapBytes[i] = oldBitmapBytes[i + offset];
}
```

But I'm still understanding how bitmaps work -- and shifting to the left and wrapping around bytes is still a bit confusing to me

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you wanting to shift an image so it's display shows it's shifted left or right, or just to offset the start by 40 pixels? You would need to know the image dimensions, the bit-depth, number of colour channels, packing order, stride of each line etc.. your question lacks all of this information

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my post

Comment: Are you working in C or C++? The tags are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I originally thought the OP just wanted to clip the image, it sounds like they want to wrap it so the left/right 40 pixels appear on the opposite side

Comment: 1-bit bitmap with width 240 requires padding. Try changing the width to 256 so that padding is not required, then try width = 240. For wrap around effect, just draw the part of the bitmap to the left, another part to the right. Your image drawing library can do this very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain your goal very well, but I presume you want the "wrap-around" to be on a per-line basis. So, the *n* pixels at the left of each line should end up flowing to the right of the line instead.

Just shifting the bytes around the whole image, you will instead end up with those bytes on the *previous* line, because the bytes are in a 1D sequence and you didn't build in any logic to pay heed to the notional "width" of your image.

If you want 2D logic, you need to write 2D code.

Here's a full example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Some constants
    const size_t width = 6;
    const size_t height = 4;
    const size_t bitmapBytes = width*height;

    // Actual data
    char oldBitmapBytes[bitmapBytes] =
    {
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
        '.', ',', '/', '~', '#', '$',
        '!', '-', '!', '+', '!', '?'
    };

    char newBitmapBytes[bitmapBytes];

    // Variables
    const size_t x_offset = 2;

    // Some utilities
    auto convertCoordsToIndex = [&](const size_t x, const size_t y)
    {
        return y*width + x;
    };

    auto printBitmap = [&](const char* bitmapBytes)
    {
        for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < width; col++)
                std::cout << bitmapBytes[convertCoordsToIndex(col, row)];
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    };

    // Display original bitmap
    printBitmap(oldBitmapBytes);

    // Shift by x_offset

    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
       for (size_t col = 0; col < width; col++)
       {
          const size_t adjustedCol = (col + x_offset) % width;
          const size_t oldIndex = convertCoordsToIndex(col, row);
          const size_t newIndex = convertCoordsToIndex(adjustedCol, row);

          newBitmapBytes[newIndex] = oldBitmapBytes[oldIndex];
        }
    }

    // Display shifted bitmap
    std::cout << '\n';
    printBitmap(newBitmapBytes);
}

// Output:
//   123456
//   abcdef
//   .,/~#$
//   !-!+!?
//   
//   561234
//   efabcd
//   #$.,/~
//   !?!-!+
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e87fc82b609d12a4))

The interesting bit is near the bottom, where I loop in a row-aware and column-aware way, copying bytes from the old bitmap to the new one but using *addition* (`+`) and *modulo* (`%`) to offset which column I'm copying in each case.

Ultimately, it's just maths!

We can do this in-place, too (i.e. no second array needed), and [doing it with `std::rotate`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db9a724f4eb453ea) makes things marginally simpler maybe.

Note that this will not work for actual bitmaps in general, as many formats (including BMP) have not only headers but also line padding. You'd have to build in some allowances for those things.

Comment: a modern method would be to use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) as this is what the OP wants on a per row basis but this at least explains what is happening for each pixel +1

Comment: @EdChum True, that'd be a great way to do it in place too.

Comment: @EdChum Added the option :D Note though how it doesn't really make things much simpler/clearer. If anything, I'd say it's harder to follow. Anyway that's for the reader to decide. (Don't think it's worth adding the second example to the prose though)

Comment: I agree just throwing a STL version doesn't help understand the fundamentals, something that isn't clear is whether this bitmap is bottom up or down. I thought bitmaps were bottom up so you have to copy from the bottom line upwards: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/top-down-vs--bottom-up-dibs, just my thoughts, although we don't know the target so this could be just fluff

Comment: @EdChum If you're rotating width-wise it doesn't matter

Comment: You're so wonderful @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I will play around with this when I get home.  Thank you so much for the illustrations and examples!